# Domain transfer from Yahoo to Godaddy. Google apps downtime

Tags: domain, g-suite

I am moving my domain from Yahoo to Godaddy (cause yahoo charges ridiculously hugh amounts than others). My problem is I use this domain for Google apps and one of those is my custom email.
So here are a few questions that I have -
1) Godaddy told me there is going to be a 48 hours of downtime. Is there anything that I can do to minimize the downtime?
2) Will I lose all the email that I get during this downtime? or they be stored in the cloud and bulk emailed me once my domain is up with Godaddy? If they are lost is there any workaround to forward them to my gmail during the downtime (i know sounds stupid, but I have to ask).

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you're making a massive mistake.  I'm recommending that people move away from Godaddy, not towards them.  They're awful.

Answer (score 1):

The registry will take some time to update, but you can expect that Yahoo will continue to handle the requests properly passing them on to Google apps until GoDaddy's transfer propogates to the registry. I would therefore expect no downtime.

Answer (score 0):

The general idea to have DNS transfers going smoothly is to lower the TTL before doing the changes. For example, if you lower the TTL of all your records to 5 minutes, than changes will propagate in 5 minutes max. The important TTL that you should not forget, is the delegation from your parent zone (.com, .org, .ch, ...).

Now, I dont know if Yahoo lets you tune all those TTLs. Worst case, you can use editdns.net or some other third party service during the transition.

I have no idea how you can manage .com delegations, as I only use .ch names ...

Answer (score 0):

Have a secondary DNS from ZoneEdit and have high TTLs for MX records. In most cases, by the time the transfer propogates to the registry, requests should have been already been handled by Google Apps.

Answer (score 0):

A good registrar setup will allow you to configure you DNS entries as soon as the transfer is agreed (possible as soon as it is initiated) and the other should serve requests for a short time after the transfer is complete so downtime is going to be minimal - as soon as the new delegation to GoDaddy is seen by DNS lookups all your entries pointing to Google will be there ready and Yahoo should still be serving the right values long enough to account for their normal TTL values.

Of course this is all "should" not "definitely will" and things could sometimes go wrong, so plan for a little downtime anyway (at least warn you users it might happen).

Answer (score 0):

Actually, in this case since you're just moving the domain registration, I'd recommend against following the usual advice of lowering the TTL. If you're going to keep the email and apps pointed at Google, raise the TTL to as high as possible! If you can put it at 259200 (three days) or more!

Any decent registry should be capable of putting the records on their NS servers more or less immediately, so downtime should be minimal. The claimed downtime of 48 hours is ridiculous.